# Godot: In a group of two ViewportContainers, only the second one receives mouse events?

Tags: viewport, godot, gdscript

I am experiencing a frustrating situation with the 3D FPS game I am working on. The goal is to be able to have side-by-side local co-op with both a keyboard & mouse and a controller where they control separate players. I have already been able to accomplish side-by-side co-op like that with two controllers. And specifically, I am trying to capture the mouse's  movement for the KBM player so I can rotate his camera accordingly.

Here is what the tree looks like for the Viewports:

```
-- Control
------ HboxContainer
---------- ViewportContainer
-------------- Viewport
---------- ViewportContainer2
-------------- Viewport
```

The nodes are all expanded and stretched properly. I have tried all I can think of with the mouse filtering on the Control, HboxContainer, and ViewportContainer nodes. I've also tried setting "Handle Input Locally" to true for both Viewports. And then I tried attaching a script to both ViewportContainers that looks like this:

```
extends ViewportContainer

func _ready():
    set_process_unhandled_input(true)

func _input(event):
    print(event)
    if event is InputEventMouse:
        print('#############\n', self.name, ' mouse event')
```

The purpose of this was to see if I could catch mouse events in the ViewportContainers and then pass the event down to the Viewport where the keybaord & mouse player lives. However, the only output I got was a bunch of this:

```
[InputEventMouseMotion:xxx]
#############
ViewportContainer2 mouse event
```

And this is where I noticed the weird and frustrating behavior. ONLY the second ViewportContainer is receiving mouse events. And further proving that behavior, I confirmed that the device combination works perfectly when the controller player is using the left (first) Viewport and the KBM player is using the right (second) Viewport.

So what I really need help with is figuring out if there is a way that I can receive mouse input in the first Viewport with the configuration I have. If not, I am open to trying different tree configurations. I just need to be able to have side-by-side Viewports that evenly split the screen.

**Edit**

Here is my code for handling the mouse input and rotating the appropriate player's camera accordingly:

```
if not usingController && event is InputEventMouseMotion && Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
    rotate_y(-event.relative.x * mouseSensitivity)
    camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * mouseSensitivity)
    var cameraRotation: Vector3 = camera.rotation_degrees
    cameraRotation.x = clamp(cameraRotation.x,  (angleOfFreedom * -1) - 90, angleOfFreedom - 90)
    camera.rotation_degrees = cameraRotation
```

Answer (score 1):

After all the research I did, I was sure that a control node somewhere that was consuming the mouse events, but I just could not figure out where. And I kept digging and digging and trying different things until I finally realized that my Player scene has a HUD which contains multiple control nodes. And what do you know? Those controls all had mouse filter set to "stop". Setting those to "ignore" fixed my issue and now everything works as I expected it to. I had been looking everywhere EXCEPT for the Player scene for Control nodes that might be causing that. So for anyone that might stumble upon an issue like this in the future, just keep on looking through EVERY scene in your tree for control nodes that have a mouse filter property set.

Answer (score 0):

This is what comes to mind: You can make an autoload, e.g called `Pointing2D` with an script like this:

```
extends Node2D


var position:Vector2D


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if not (
        event is InputEventScreenDrag
        or event is InputEventScreenTouch
        or event is InputEventMouse
    ):
        return

    position = event.position
```

Then read `Pointing2D.position` where you need it. For example in `_process`. If you want to know how much it moved between frames you can store the old value:

```
var old_pointing_position:Vector2

func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var pointing_position := Pointing2D.position
    var delta_pointing_position := pointing_position - old_pointing_position
    old_pointing_position = pointing_position
```

Comment: Huh, that is an interesting idea. Will this work for a 3D scene, though? Looks like I only need an event.relative.x and event.relative.y so a Vector2D should work. I have updated the original post with the code for handling the mouse input.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, it should work. No, the fact that it is `Node2D` is not an issue. I'm telling you to get the difference in `_process` instead of taking the last `relative` because there could be - and likely are - multiple events between frames. You can also add more things to the script if you need to (e.g. I have a version that includes dragging, and another version that identifies what 3D the mouse is hovering over - that one tied to a `Viewport` so it won't be useful for you as is). By the way, I did this to ease refactoring, not something related to multiple `Viewport`s.